# Add textbox upon checking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes (`choice_0` and `choice_1`). I must be able to select one or both and it should add textbox next to it.
My problem is that if I enable one of checkboxes it will add one textbox field below it and if I want to click other it probably adds it but they are at same position so I still see only one.
When I disable checkbox field still stays and it is not removed.
I will use that textfields to send parameters to my Django and use it for filters.

Both checkboxes enabled:

[image]

Now when I disable them:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    display:block;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:block;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myclass" value="year" name="year" placeholder="TEXT">Year</input>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myclass" value="name" name="name" placeholder="TEXT">Name</input>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>

    <script>
$('.myclass').click(function(){
  $(this).prop('checked') ? 
  $('form').append(`<input id="${$(this).val()}input"></input>`) :
  $(`form #${$(this).val()}input`).remove();
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

formy.py

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    filter = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'Something'), ('2', 'Something1')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': 'choice'}))
    name = forms.TextInput()
    year = forms.TextInput()
```

views.py

```
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()    
    print(request.POST) # print QueryDict also
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data) # This dict contains keys (filters, and html(This is dynamically added field))
        if '1' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(naslov=form.cleaned_data['name'])
        if '2' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=form.cleaned_data['year'])
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('filtar/',views.filtar, name='filtar'), 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: assign classes, rather than id and use single click handler

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg As I am new to JS and Django I am not really sure how to do it

Comment: well first of all please post all the involved code.

Comment: @MauriceNino I Update original post with all code needed, if I am missing something I'll update it

Comment: @justStarting : check out my example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.myclass').click(function(){
  $(this).prop('checked') ? 
  $('form').append(`<input id="${$(this).val()}input" style="display:block;margin:5px" placeholder="${$(this).val()} details"></input>`) :
  $(`form #${$(this).val()}input`).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class="myclass" value="option1">Option 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="myclass" value="option2">Option 2</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You, am I able to put one checkbox below other one? If i use "<br>" it will do the trick but both textboxs will still be added next to second one. If not am I able to make textbox description somehow?

Comment: Play around with CSS, like `display: block` (see my updated code). And don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I updated original code on post above, when I add placeholder it still shows me nothing in the textfield.

Comment: @justStarting : make sure you follow exactly the pattern implemented above

Comment: I need to ask You one more thing, how can I access those created textfields, what would be their ID or Value?

Comment: @justStarting : they have dynamic id's comprised by the value of checkbox that triggered its creation, appended by 'input' (it is done by this part: `id="${$(this).val()}input"`), e.g. for the first checkbox in my example that would be 'option1input'. You may find out those by inspecting your HTML source upon creation of those input fields.

Comment: Thank You, I find out that my variables are "nameinput" and "yearinput". I am not sure if You are familiar with Django but I am getting troubles in "views.py" to collect data from those variables when checkbox is on. I tried to print it there with "message = request.GET.get('nameinput')" and "print (message)" but I got nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you out with python part. If there's anything I can suggest regarding javascript, feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
  $('#choice_0').click(function() {
      if (!counter) {
          $('<input>').attr({
              id: 'foo',
              name: 'text'
          }).appendTo('form');
        $('#foo')[0].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        $('#foo')[0].style.display = 'none';
      counter++;
  })
```

Repeat for the other checkbox.

Comment: That will unnecessarily append many instances of the input field and hide those upon multiple checking/unchecking. My another concern - there's no sense to duplicate code implementing same behavior for each and every option (at least, if you're not getting paid by the number of characters).

Comment: You are write about duplicating the code but I just give a taste how it can be dealt with by using condition. Thanks for your comment and clarification.